# How to create a keyboard shortcut to run gnome-system-monitor

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I installed the gnome system monitor from the app center and was wondering how to create a keyboard shortcut to open it quickly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Settings -> keyboard -> shortcuts -> custom

Comment: In the enter command section, do i enter a terminal command? and then how do i actually set the shortcut, it seemed to not bw working properly